# How can you change Windows 10 keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I have several apps that I use with keyboard shortcuts that I'm used to and the new shortcuts built into Windows 10 have taken some of them over. These are already ingrained habits and I don't want to change nor do I care too much about what the new shortcuts do.

So, is there a way to override Windows's keyboard shortcuts, at least for the new shortcuts in Windows 10?  Search the interwebs and my windows settings has not yielded anything yet.

Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you list the shortcuts...

Comment: What shortcuts specifically do you want to change?

Comment: [Windows Key] + A for starters.  I had that set to switch context to SlickRun, but it obviously no longer works.  Instead I get the fancy Action Center

Comment: @ManojSawai, that is a little disappointing to read, but thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether that can be done with Windows 10 out of the box.

However, if you are willing to install [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), you could map one keyboard shortcut to another keyboard shortcut.

#### Example script

```
#a::                ; Intercept Win+A (and don't open the Action Center)
MsgBox, Hi, Dan!    ; Display a message in a message box
                    ; Here you could invoke another keyboard shortcut 
return
```