# Windows 10 - What is Ctrl+Alt+F1 and how to disable it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hotkeys

I've an application who offers me the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

But Windows 10 opens the Task-Switcher instead. I found out, that this behaviour disappears when I kill the explorer-process, but I don't found an option yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a default windows feature.im not 100% sure but it could be caused by additional software that comes with the Intel Graphics chip.
First use task manager to kill the intel application/service:

if that works go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108927/ctrl-alt-f8-disconnects-displays): and follow the answer's directions

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is not the default hotkey on Windows 10.
It may trigger Intel HD Graphics Control Panel - Display Panel on some computers.

What you can do is to [Remap and Set Global Hotkeys on Windows 10 with Auto Hotkey](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/remap-and-set-global-hotkeys-on-windows-10-with-auto-hotkey)

Also read

- [How to modify windows 10 Keyboard shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/987834/how-to-modify-windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts)
- [How can you change Windows 10 keyboard shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/1077513/how-can-you-change-windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

If it triggers the Intel HD Graphics control panel do this to disable shortcut keys:

1. Open old Windows Control Panel (Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd>, write
   `control` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>)
2. Open the **Intel HD Graphics** element
3. Click on **Options and assistance**
4. Click on **disable** short keys